# XSL:FO Different list-item-label per level

Tags: xslt, pdf-generation, html-lists, apache-fop

I'm using *Apache FOP* to generate PDFs from my web application, where users can edit richtext using *CKEditor*.

My problem is that users sometimes use different levels of indentation in (un-)ordered lists, e.g.:

- List item level 1

  - List item level 2

The CKEditor shows different bulletins per level (or indentation), but the generated PDFs do not, because my template looks like this:

```xsl
<!-- Lists -->
<xsl:template match="ul|ol" mode="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="li" mode="content">
        <xsl:with-param name="ordered">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()='ol'"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="li" mode="content">
    <xsl:param name="ordered"/>
    <xsl:variable name="label">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$ordered='true'">
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                .
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                &#8226;
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <fo:list-block padding-bottom="0pt">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$label"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates mode="content"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>
```

So how can I set the label variable depending on which level of indentation I'm at?

Something like:

- 1st level: &#8226
- 2nd level: &#9702
- 3rd level: &#8269

Thanks in advance, ~Fabi

EDIT: So the solution suggested by @fafl looks like this:

```
<!-- Lists -->
    <xsl:template match="ul|ol" mode="content">
        <xsl:param name="depth" select="0"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="li" mode="content">
            <xsl:with-param name="ordered">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()='ol'"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="depth">
                <xsl:value-of select="$depth + 1"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li" mode="content">
        <xsl:param name="depth" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="ordered"/>
        <xsl:variable name="label">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$ordered='true'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                    .
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$depth = 1">
                            &#8226; <!--filled circle-->
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$depth = 2">
                            &#9702; <!--not-filled circle-->
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            &#9632; <!--black square -->
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <fo:list-block padding-bottom="0pt">
            <fo:list-item>
                <fo:list-item-label>
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$label"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-label>
                <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
                    <fo:block>
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="content">
                            <xsl:with-param name="depth">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$depth"/>
                            </xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:list-item-body>
            </fo:list-item>
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a parameter "depth" to both templates with a default value of 1. On each recursive call of "ul|ol" increase it by 1. Then you can query it inside both templates.

Comment: This works great. Thanks. Should (how can) I add the finished templates for future visitors?